# Correlation matrix clustering

Tags: matlab, correlation

I have a correlation matrix which defines the correlation between different super voxels in a 3d image. (denoted by corrMat).

I tried to cluster it using hierarchical clustering (linkage and cluster functions on Matlab).

I am having a hard time using the output of the above functions on my image (for example - coloring different voxels according to their cluster).

I guess I just don't understand the output values of linkage.. How can I color the voxels based on their correlation?

Here's what I have so far. the line assigning values into groupedImg is obviously wrong.

```
dis = 1 - corrMat';

Z = linkage(dis, 'median'); % Hierechial clustering

cutoff = 0.5*(max(Z(:,3))); % 50% cutoff

groups = cluster(Z,'cutoff',cutoff,'criterion','distance');

groupedImg = zeros(size(Img,1),size(Img,2),size(Img,3));

voxelsMapGroups = cat(2,voxelsMap,groups);

for i=1:1:size(voxelsMapGroups,1)
    x=voxelsMapGroups(i,1);
    sizeX=voxelsMapGroups(i,4)-1;
    y=voxelsMapGroups(i,2);
    sizeY=voxelsMapGroups(i,5)-1;
    z=voxelsMapGroups(i,3);
    sizeZ=voxelsMapGroups(i,6)-1;
    groupedImg(x:(x+sizeX),y:(y+sizeY),z:(z+sizeZ)) = voxelsMapGroups(i,7);
end
```

voxelsMap simply divides the voxels into super-voxels to reduce computational complexity.

Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: You'd want to paint the voxels according to cluster, rigth? not linkage. See `openExample('stats/CLusterDataAndPlotTheResultExample')` (run this in MATLAB)

Comment: Yes, I'd want to paint the voxels according to cluster. I am not sure why you directed me to this example...?

Comment: To the example called Cluster Data and Plot The Results? Because... plots data resulting from clustering? what are you having problems with?

Comment: Thanks for replying. 
I am having problems with coloring the original image based on the clusters. I can't seen to find the link between the groups and the original voxels

Comment: I am now trying another approach of graph representation and segmentation but would still like to figure out this approach as well

Comment: We can not help with that because this is not a [mcve] and there are no pixel values here. You can easily see how `groups` is related to`dis`, if you know ho `dis` is related to pixel data, then it should be easy